# Как защитить фотографии от скачивания?

Tags: безопасность

В моем проекте важно что бы фото были защищены и в идеале нельзя было их скачать. Какие способы защиты можно использовать?

Comment: Не показывай их никому, и вообще нигде не пиши, что они есть - не будет ни возможности их скачать, ни соблазна...

Comment: Никак. Всегда есть принципиально неустранимая [аналоговая брешь](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D1%8C). Разве что не показывать их никому, да

Comment: @Akina ответ достойный мэйл ру. На самом деле я имел ввиду способы вроде шифрования или снижения качества или цифровой метки что бы ее можно было хотя бы отследить. Есть предположения?

Comment: @Bitrix24 шифрование всегда можно расшифровать, а пережать фотографии в низкое качество вам и так никто не мешает хоть в том же Paint. Отслеживать перемещение кучки байт тоже принципиально невозможно, это вам не GPS-жучок какой-нибудь

Comment: @andreymal можно добавить метку (несколько пикселей) и по ней отследить фотку

Comment: @Bitrix24 и что вы с этой меткой будете делать? Ну залью я ваше фото с меткой на свой сайт, о существовании которого вы никогда в жизни не знали, что дальше?

Comment: Просто поставьте водяной знак на картинку

Comment: @AhmedAyman123 водяной знак никак не помешает собственно скачать фотографию. А при должных умениях фотошопа его можно ещё и замазать

Comment: *ответ достойный мэйл ру.* Ну какой вопрос... надеюсь, не надо рассказывать, что для показывания на экране фотографии - её сперва надо скачать? что вступает в прямое противоречие с тезисом *в идеале нельзя было их скачать*. Я бы сказал так - Вы ещё и сами до конца не понимаете, что надо (иначе не было бы таких вопиющих противоречий в формулировке).

Comment: *На самом деле я имел ввиду способы вроде шифрования* Всё одно для показывания надо расшифровать - во всяком случае в видеопамяти оно будет нешифрованное. *или снижения качества* Вот уж элементарно... *цифровой метки что бы ее можно было хотя бы отследить* Стеганография? так тема вполне проработана во всех основных применениях, включая скрытую информацию об авторских правах - почитайте.

Comment: @Akina без вашего разрешения я бы форумы не прошурстил две недели назад) Если есть тезисы то пожалуйста предлагайте. Это вроде не стэндам площадка для обмена шутками (я знаю какой у меня никнейм :D).

Comment: @andreymal А дальше мы можем понять какой юзер сделал это и выставить ему иск в суд. Все просто.

Comment: @Bitrix24 чтобы узнать, какой юзер сделал это, нужно сперва узнать, что это самое «это» вообще произошло. Откуда вы вообще узнаете, что кто-то скачал вашу фотографию? Если вы об этом не узнаете, то и иск в суд не подадите.

Comment: @andreymal эти фотки доступны только авторизованным пользователям это раз. Есть логи апача и не сложно даже без авторизации сопоставить кто запрашивал контент и подпись на фотке...

Comment: @Bitrix24 в логах апача скачивание ничем не будет отличаться от простого просмотра. По такой логике, с учётом возможности замазывания метки, вы рискуете подать в суд на тех, кто на самом деле ни в чём не виноват.

Comment: @andreymal ну так как мы выяснили просмотр и есть скачивание. Сопоставляем кто смотрел и подпись. Где хэши сошлись там и произошла кража авторских прав.

Comment: @Bitrix24 сопоставляем с чем? Ещё раз, откуда вы вообще узнаете, что кто-то что-то скачал? В логах апача скачивание отличить нельзя.

Comment: @andreymal ну короче такой способ есть) Я не буду расписывать алгоритм. Это за рамками вопроса и вопрошающего.

Comment: @Bitrix24 или вам кажется, что он есть, а на самом деле он не будет работать. Судя по вашим остальным комментариям, дела обстоят именно так.

Comment: https://cameralabs.org/3307-soveti-po-zaschite-fotografiy - не знаю, поможет или нет)

Comment: **Мозаичное изображение:** некоторые фотографы намеренно делят свое изображение на четыре или более частей и соединяют их в одно изображение уже на сайте. При взгляде на фотографию, оно выглядит как цельное фото, но если они щелкнуть правой кнопкой мыши или попытаться перетащить изображение, вы получите только одну из его частей.

Comment: **Отключение правой кнопки мыши:**
вы можете найти код JavaScript, который позволит предотвратить срабатывание правой кнопкой мыши в любом месте вашей страницы. Есть способы, благодаря которым данную систему защиты можно обойти. Поэтому это не защитит ваши фотографии от настоящих воров, которые целенаправленно хотят скопировать снимки, это скорее защита от случайных пользователей, которые из праздного любопытства и интереса хотят сохранить ваши снимки.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Защитить изображения полностью не получится. Можете почитать про [DRM](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8B_%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2), но даже это не защитит вас от копирования изображений.

Например, вы настроили DRM, сделали доступ к контенту возможным только с мобильных устройств. Скриншоты и скринкасты делать нельзя, и, казалось бы, все довольны. Однако найдётся пользователь, который запустит приложение на виртуальном устройстве и снимет данные с него, или рутует свой гаджет.

Про десктопные платформы или веб-платформы и говорить не стоит - тут у приложения куда меньше привилегий и способов ограничить возможности пользователя.

P.S. Кстати, недавно на Хабре была опубликована достаточно [интересная статья](https://habr.com/ru/post/505702/). Можете почитать на досуге :)

Comment: Спасибо большое. Думал о топорной нарезке. Это для нас последний вариант. Возможно мы к нему прибегнем вместе с цифровой меткой что бы было понятно кто скачал данную фотку. Идея такая что цифровой токен у каждого свой и при скачивании он остается на фотке и тогда ее можно трэйсить и выставлять иск за копирование без разрешения автора.

Comment: @Bitrix24 скачиваем фотку с двух-трёх разных юзеров — накладываем друг на друга в фотошопе — метки выявляются — замазываем. Ваша схема как минимум в такой «наивной» интерпретации работать не будет

Comment: @Bitrix24 ну и банально можно исказить фотку (уменьшить, слегка повернуть, размыть и т.п.) — метка может оказаться неустойчивой к таким изменениям и стать нечитаемой

Comment: @andreymal - устойчивые ватермарки обычно накладывают, переведя изображение при помощи вейвлет-преобразования в частотно - фазовое пространство. Такая вотермарка будет при субстракции разных образцов давать рандомный шум в пределах нескольких бит, равномерно размазанный по всей картинке.А при суммировании получится мыло.

Answer (score 3):

Все довольно просто. Если ваше фото своровал неизвестно кто и смотрит на него у себя в бункере, заперев дверь, то и фиг с ним, аудитории у него нет, а значит, особо больших убытков от этого тоже нет.

Если же фото утянули журналисты и использовали в публикации, вы об этом узнаете, выполняя, например, поиск по вашим фото в Гугле, Тинае и Яндексе.

Теперь в дело вступают вотермарки, только не те вотермарки, которые огромная серая надпись поперек фотки, а настоящие, неразрушаемые обработкой цифровые вотермарки с ЭЦП и суды - юристы. Либо какой-то другой способ доказать приоритет, например, оригинальные RAW файлы.

Answer (score 2):

Любую защиту можно обойти. Главное - сделать защиту довольно сложной, чтоб стоимость обхода была выше стоимости картинок.

1. Весь код клиента должен быть обфусцированный, понятное дело.
2. Клиент с сервером поднимает WebSocket соединение, обменивается с ним ключами по [протоколу Диффи-Хеллмана](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB_%D0%94%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B8_%E2%80%94_%D0%A5%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0)
3. Сервер отдает клиенту зашифрованые куски нарезаной картинки. Картинка нарезена на кучу кусочков, как описано в [статье на хабре](https://habr.com/ru/post/505702/).
4. Картинки рендерятся не в тег img, а на несколько `Canvas`ов. У всех абсолютное позиционирование, так же запутанная `DOM`-структура, которая раз в пару секунд меняется (может это лишнее).
5. Можно прикрутить сюда `captcha` - чтоб было труднее парсить.
6. Можно сделать сложный алгоритм дешифровки, чтоб на расшифровку нужно было несколько секунд.
7. Добавить защиту от дебага - если открыт `DevTools` - скрипт прекращает работу и очищает картинки.

> Но все равно любую защиту можно обойти, например, сделав скриншот. От скриншота защитит максимум ватермарка, и то не полностью.

Так же рекомендую немного уменьшить картинку, понизить JPEG-качество, чтоб не было выгодно брать вашку картинку.

Comment: >>>> Добавить защиту от дебага - если открыт DevTools - скрипт прекращает работу и очищает картинки.
не все браузеры это отрабатывают

Comment: @Вадим, верно, но есть способы чтоб максимизировать влияние. Я знаю как минимум 3 способа отследить DevTools, думаю на практике их побольше будет

Comment: поделись - мне не удалось ни каким способом, точнее не удалось скрыть отправляемые логин пароль - в дебаге все прочитывалось, если дебаг открыть перед отправкой пост запроса.

Comment: @Вадим, Я использую код на базе [devtools-detect](https://github.com/sindresorhus/devtools-detect). Так же использую ключевое слово `debugger;` в интервале, что-то типа [этого](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41629072/5698975) кода

Comment: проверил  devtools-detect в мозиле  - на ихнем пример - NO в любом случае.....